# Jquery Drag and Drop - insert dragged div container before other container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I got some containers and want to manipulate the DOM by inserting the dragged container before the container, the dragged one is dragging over.

Means ...
This is the current placement

[image: Default]

Now I want to place the red container before the green one

[image: Insert]

and it will look this

[image: Desired]

**Important note:** I know there is Jquery UI and it's really easy to use, but I may not use it.

So I know I can use the jquery functions `.insertBefore()` and `.insertAfter()` but I am struggling with the drag-events.

Here is a small example showing my current work

```js
$(document).ready(function () { // add the events to the containers
    addDragDropToElement("divRed");
    addDragDropToElement("divBlue");
    addDragDropToElement("divGreen");
    addDragDropToElement("divYellow");
});

function addDragDropToElement(element) {
  var ele = $("#" + element);
  
    ele.prop("draggable", true); // make the div draggable

    ele.on('dragstart', function () {
        startDragging(event);
    });

    ele.on('dragenter', function () {
        enterDragging(event);
    });

    ele.on('dragover', function () {
        dragOver(event);
    });

    ele.on('dragleave', function () {
        leaveDragging(event);
    });

    ele.on('drop', function () {
        dropElement(event);
    });

    ele.on('dragend', function () {
        stopDragging(event);
    });
}

   var draggedElement = null;

function startDragging(e) {
    draggedElement = e.target;
}

function enterDragging(e) {

}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function leaveDragging(e) {

}

function dropElement(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetElement = e.target;

    $(draggedElement).insertBefore(targetElement);
}

function stopDragging(e) {

}
```

```css
#divRed{background:red;}
#divBlue{background:blue;}
#divGreen{background:green;}
#divYellow{background:yellow;}

.container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="divRed"></div>
<div class="container" id="divBlue"></div>
<div class="container" id="divGreen"></div>
<div class="container" id="divYellow"></div>
```

Would someone mind helping me filling the empty event functions below?

Comment: I think its way better if you achieve it by your own, if we do the work for you, you wont learn anything. This https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Drag_%26_Drop explains it very well but there are thousands of tutorials out there

Comment: @Doomenik I updated my post, this looks like a valid drag&drop, no ?

Comment: Looks good :) Nice done

Comment: Thank you. Your link helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

So I finally got it. If someone wants to know, how it works take this fiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    addDragDropToElement("divRed");
    addDragDropToElement("divBlue");
    addDragDropToElement("divGreen");
    addDragDropToElement("divYellow");
});

function addDragDropToElement(element) {
  var ele = $("#" + element);
  
    ele.prop("draggable", true);

    ele.on('dragstart', function () {
        startDragging(event);
    });

    ele.on('dragover', function () {
        dragOver(event);
    });

    ele.on('drop', function () {
        dropElement(event);
    });
}

var draggedElement = null; // the element that is dragged

function startDragging(e) {
    draggedElement = e.target; // store the dragged element
}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dropElement(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetElement = e.target; // the element under the dragged element

    $(draggedElement).insertBefore(targetElement); // place the dragged element before the other element
}
```

```css
#divRed{background:red;}
#divBlue{background:blue;}
#divGreen{background:green;}
#divYellow{background:yellow;}

.container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="divRed"></div>
<div class="container" id="divBlue"></div>
<div class="container" id="divGreen"></div>
<div class="container" id="divYellow"></div>
```